# Check if object is in RLMArray property of another object

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I'm looking for some efficient (or at least not so complicated) way to determine whether or not and Object is contained in an `RLMArray` property in another object.

If you look at the Realm Documentation there's something about [Inverse relationships](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#inverse-relationships), anyway, I'm not sure if this pattern fits with the behavior I'm looking for. Let's say we have a `Person` and a `Party` class. The `Party` class has a `guests` property:

```
// Party.h
@interface Party : RLMObject
// ... other property declarations
@property NSString *partyID;
@property RLMArray<Person *><Person> *guests;
@end
```

In the RLMRealm we have a "universe" of people, whether or not they'll assist to any party ever. So a person may be in the `guests` list of a few partys. When I open a party I'd like to show a list with ALL the people in the "universe". And also we should be able to notice if they're already invited.

```
+---------+---------+
| Invited | Name    |
+---------+---------+
| NO      | Orlando |
| YES     | Kim     |
| NO      | Jorge   |
| NO      | JJ      |
| YES     | Axel    |
+---------+---------+
```

If I use an Inverse Relationship, then I'll have to create a property containing the relationships in `Person`

```
// Person.h
@interface Person : RLMObject
// ...
@property (readonly) RLMLinkingObjects *assistingTo;
// ...
@end
```

so for the iteration displaying the Persons list, I'll check manually if the person was invited to the party

```
RLMResults *allPeople = [People allObjects];
Party *thisParty = [Party firstObject];

for (Person *p in allPeople) {
    if ([p.assistingTo indexOfObject:thisParty] > -1) {
        // Show the YES in the table
    } else {
        // Then the person is not attending the party
    }
}
```

Am I doing the job the right way? Is there any other way to doing so?

Answer (score 1):

Yep! You're on the right track! `RLMLinkingObjects` work with `NSPredicate` queries, so it would be very simple to fetch a list of all of the people attending a specific party like this:

```
RLMResults *allPeopleAtTheParty = [Person objectsWhere:@"%@ IN assistingTo", thisParty];
```

This would return a list of `Person` objects who had the particular `thisParty` object in their `assistingTo` array property.

If you wanted to display a table of every single `Person` and then an 'Attending/Not Attending' label, then it would get a bit tricky. You'd obviously need to load a proper list of all `Person` objects, and then compare it against your filtered list to work out which ones were invited, and which weren't.

This would *probably* be too heavy of an operation to do on-the-fly when constructing a `UITableViewCell`, so I'd elect to do it this way:

1) Create an ignored property on `Person` that tracks if they were invited or not:

```
@interface Person : RLMObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL invited;
@end

@implementation Person
+ (NSArray *)ignoredProperties
{
   return @[@"invited"];
}
@end
```

2) Query for the master list, and the sorted list:

```
RLMResults *allPeople = [Person allObjects];
RLMResults *partyPeople = [Person objectsWhere:@"%@ IN assistingTo", thisParty];
```

3) Loop through each person in the `partyPeople` list, and update the `invited` property in their equivalent entry in the `allPeople` list:

```
for (Person *person in partyPeople) {
   NSInteger personIndex = [allPeople indexOfObject:person];
   if (personIndex == NSNotFound) {
      continue;
   }

   allPeople[personIndex].invited = YES;
}
```

4. Set up the `UITableView`, using `allPeople` as its data source.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: And what if I'm using an UITableView and in the `-cellForRowAtindexPath` I do the check I posted on my question:

`Person *currentPerson = [allPeople objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`
`if ([party.guests indexOfObject:currentPerson] > -1) {`
`    // Show "YES" in the table`
`}`

The table is making the iteration anyway. The question may be reduced at: Does the method `-indexOfObject:` can do the job efficiently?

Comment: Yep! That's what I meant by using `allPeople` as your data source; you use that one when constructing cells in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Without explicitly storing the 'invited' state in your Realm file, yes, sorting via `indexOfObject` is probably the best way to go. But for performance, I'd recommend doing it how I specified. Don't use `indexOfObject` directly inside `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`.